# How to repair unbootable Fedora install

Tags: linux, fedora, yum

How do you repair/reinstall Fedora without deleting any existing partitions or data?

I was attempting to upgrade some old Fedora 13 servers to 17, following the instructions in the [wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_Fedora_using_yum). After the 14->15 upgrade, rebooting resulted in the output:

```
Dropping to debug shell.

sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
dracut:/#
```

Running dmesg also shows:

```
dracut Warning: No root device "block:/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root" found
```

Googling shows this error is typically related to some weird RAID issues, but my server is a virtual machine not using any RAID. Using a rescue CD, I can `chroot /mnt/sysimage`, and all packages and data still seems to be there. How do I make the system bootable again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it's not uncommon for Fedora's upgrade process to corrupt the /boot/initramfs filesystem, resulting in an unbootable system.

Using a tip I found [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-245377.html), the solution is to boot using a Fedora Live CD, and select "rescue installed system" from the menu. Then walk through the menu to get to the rescue shell. Then mount the system using `chroot /mnt/sysimage`. The tip recommended repairing initramfs by running:

```
mv /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r)-nouveau.img
dracut /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)
```

However, since you'll be running the Live CD's kernel, this will likely fail if your system's kernel version does not exactly match the Live CD. My Live CD was using a 2.6.* kernel, but I had a 3.4.* kernel installed, so I ran:

```
mv /boot/initramfs-3.4.2-1.fc16.x86_64.img /boot/initramfs-3.4.2-1.fc16.x86_64-nouveau.img
dracut /boot/initramfs-3.4.2-1.fc16.x86_64.img 3.4.2-1.fc16.x86_64
exit
```

Afterwards, removing the Live CD and then rebooting resulted in a bootable system.

Comment: Did this solve the problem? You never marked it as solved.